# Good qualities of deceased now available for others to practise. Is there a source?

Tags: death, middos-character-traits

I have heard several times at Hespedim (funeral orations) that the good qualities of the person who passed away are now available to be picked up by those of us still alive.

In the sense that the dead person cannot practise these qualities anymore, this is obvious. My question is whether there is a source for the statement.

Comment: The end of Masechet Sotah has quite a few examples of the opposite.

Comment: @Alex The end of Masechet Sotah has examples of good qualities of a person who passed away not being _available_ to be picked up by those still alive? I thought the good qualities were _avaiable_, just people didn't pick them up.

Comment: When my late father was niftar, I was told this idea b'sheim the Arizal

Comment: I;ve heard this from the Yaavetz. Not sure exactly where

Comment: Does that statement imply that those good qualities were not available to be picked up by others as well while the person is still alive?

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara (Berachos 6b - cited below) quotes Rav Sheishes who said that the primary reward for those participating in a eulogy comes through *deluyei*. Rashi (cited below) translates *deluyei* as crying and wailing. Others translate *deluyei* as drawing (as in drawing water from a well). The idea being that at the time of the eulogy, those participating can *draw* the good qualities of the deceased.

---

אמרו בגמ' (ברכות ו:) אמר רב ששת אגרא דהספדא דלויי וכ' רש"י (ד"ה דלויי) להרים קול בלשון נהי ועגמת נפש שיבכו השומעים

Comment: If anyone knows who the "others" are, post the comment and I will gladly edit the answer. I can't remember who was the one who offered that interpretation.